# Why does removeChild remove every element instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a very hard time adding HTML to a webpage the way I want to.  I'm currently working on a resume creator webpage, but when I click the remove school button while more than 2 schools are listed, the associated javascript removes every school except for the first one.  The removeChild function is not working as it is supposed to.  My code is listed below.  Specifically, if you run the code, then click add school twice, and then click remove school, it will remove Schools 2 and 3, while it should only remove school 3.  So something is wrong with my removeSchool function I would think.  But nothing is wrong as far as I can tell.

Also, if anyone has any idea of a better way of doing what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

```js
const schools = document.getElementById("schools");
var num_schools = 1;
var add_school_button = `<button id="addschool" onclick="addSchool();">Add School</button>`;
var remove_school_button = `<button id="removeschool" onclick="removeSchool();">Remove School</button>`;
var new_school_html = `<table id="school[]">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">School []</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="schoolname[]">School Name: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="schoolname[]" size="50" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="schoollocation[]">Location: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="schoollocation[]" size="50" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="schoolyear[]">Year Graduated: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="schoolyear[]" size="50" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="schooldegree[]">Degree Earned: </label></td><td><input type="text" id="schooldegree[]" size="50" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>`;

function addSchool() {
  schools.removeChild(document.getElementById("addschool"));
  if (num_schools > 1) {
    schools.removeChild(document.getElementById("removeschool"));
  }
  num_schools++;
  schools.innerHTML += new_school_html.replace(/\[\]/g, num_schools.toString());
  schools.innerHTML += add_school_button;
  schools.innerHTML += remove_school_button;
}

function removeSchool() {
  schools.removeChild(document.getElementById("school" + num_schools.toString()));
  num_schools--;
  if (num_schools == 1) {
    schools.removeChild(document.getElementById("removeschool"));
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.maincol {
  width: 50%;
}

.maincol>* {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.maincol>h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#schools>table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Resume Creator</h1>
<form>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Identifying Information</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Full Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="address">Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="phone">Phone Number: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <p>Enter a comma-separated list of skills. E.g. Guest Services, Loss Prevention, Product Promotion, Etc.</p>
    <textarea id="skill_list" rows=4 cols=90></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <div id="schools">
      <table id="school1">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center">School 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoolname1">School Name: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoolname1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoollocation1">Location: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoollocation1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoolyear1">Year Graduated: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoolyear1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schooldegree1">Degree Earned: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schooldegree1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="addschool" onclick="addSchool();">Add School</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should look into clone and templates

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify for each button `type = "button"` so that it doesn't reload the page every time you press it. Like so :
`<button id="removeschool" type = "button" onclick="removeSchool();">Remove School</button>`.

Although I would suggest you put your buttons outside the table so that you don't have to add them with javascript every time you add/delete a school. (for the delete button just hide it when you have only one school and display it when you have multiple schools).

Also I think its better in the future to use classes instead of just adding plain strings to the HTML body. Your code would be cleaner and easier to edit.

Comment: Thank you so so so so so much.  I've been hitting myself for hours because NOTHING has been working.  I think I love you.

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan, I didn't see your answer as I was writing my own in the same time. I think Ben might be a beginner (like me) and probably got a bit lost since you changed pretty much the whole code.

Comment: @mplungjan I appreciate that you took the time to answer my question, but your answer wasn't quite what I was looking for.  As Aniry said, I'm a beginner.  I wasn't looking to re-invent how I was doing this, just for the answer to my question.  And this answer is the exact answer to what I asked.

Comment: @Ben Nobody forced you to use any of my code. I can of course only blame myself for improving your script as requested instead of just writing `give the button a type="button"` and get all the love ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. IDs must be unique
2. Use type="button" or use preventDefault (you are submitting your form now on each click)
3. Delegate

Using

```
<button type="button" class="addschool">
<button type="button" class="removeschool">
```

and

```
document.getElementById("schools").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("removeschool")) {
    tgt.closest("table").remove();
  }
  else if (tgt.classList.contains("addschool")) addSchool();
})
```

Also look into

[clone templates](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+clone+template&oq=javascript+clone+template)

Here is a clone example. I renumber the schools whenever I add or remove one

I moved the add outside schools and remove to the header

```js
const schools = document.getElementById("schools");
const firstSchool = document.getElementById("school1");
const renum = () =>   schools.querySelectorAll(".num").forEach((school,i) => school.innerText = (i+1))


function addSchool() {
  const newSchool = firstSchool.cloneNode(true);
  newSchool.querySelector(".removeschool").removeAttribute("hidden")
  schools.appendChild(newSchool)
  renum()
}

schools.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("removeschool")) {
    tgt.closest("table").remove();
    renum()
  } 
})
document.getElementById("addschool").addEventListener("click",addSchool);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.maincol {
  width: 50%;
}

.maincol>* {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.maincol>h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#schools>table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Resume Creator</h1>
<form>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Identifying Information</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Full Name: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="address">Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email Address: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="phone">Phone Number: </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <p>Enter a comma-separated list of skills. E.g. Guest Services, Loss Prevention, Product Promotion, Etc.</p>
    <textarea id="skill_list" rows=4 cols=90></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="maincol">
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <div id="schools">
      <table id="school1">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">School <span class="num">1</span><span style="float:right"><button type="button" hidden class="removeschool" >Remove</button></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoolname1">School Name: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoolname1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoollocation1">Location: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoollocation1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schoolyear1">Year Graduated: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schoolyear1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="schooldegree1">Degree Earned: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="schooldegree1" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="addschool">Add School</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But there is at no point more than one addschool or removeschool button on the screen.

Comment: Ah, ok, you can still delegate.

Comment: The code will still work since it only removes the closest table

Comment: You are mixing strings and arrays for the table id's.

Comment: @Vbudo Are you addressing me? Please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I's thinking of using DOM remove method instead of removeChild method. Since you are already using getElementById so remove will do just fine.

```js
function removeSchool() {
  document.getElementById("school" + num_schools.toString()).remove(); // here changed removeChild method to remove
  num_schools--;
  if (num_schools == 1) {
    document.getElementById("removeschool").remove(); // here changed removeChild method to remove
  }
}
```

[Remove DOM Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_remove.asp)